# Hide scrollbar in dynamic area

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to hide the scrollbar in a dynamically sized element in CSS and allow the contents to take up the space where the scrollbar was. I have managed to hide the bar by adding some extra padding to the right of my element that pushes it out of an `overflow: hidden` div, however the content does not expand to fill the space the scrollbar occupied.

I do not want to use any static values for scrollbar width as this changes between browsers and some browsers (like Chrome) change the scrollbar width when zoomed.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kv4soak8/), uncomment to hide scrollbar.

With scrollbar:
[image: with scrollbar]

Without scrollbar:
[image: without scrollbar]

Comment: So do you not want a scrollbar at all?

Comment: @SamirChahine No, I would like to be able to scroll with a mouse/javascript but I do not want a visible bar.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a scrollable div but no scroll bar, place it inside a parent div. set the parent div to overflow hidden and the inner div to overflow auto. Make the parent div slightly skinnier than the inner div so that the scroll bar from the inner div is not shown. if created dynamically, simply set the width at time of rendering using jQuery or other js.

```css
.parentDiv {
   width: 301px;
   height: 450px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
    
.parentDiv .innerDiv {
   width: 320px;
   height: 450px;
   overflow: auto; 
}
```

PS:- I just put this together to show the effect. Note that it sets the width in the CSS for both divs.  The effect as such does not require JS or JQuery, however, setting style rules dynamically will. Or use PHP and load the widths at the page load/render. You might investigate "calc" for the CSS, but I don't know how well that is supported in different browsers. Alternatively - use percentages for the CSS, just make the parent div skinner than the inner div.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <title>Scrollable Div Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <style>
        .parentDiv
        {
            width: 301px;
            height: 450px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
    .parentDiv .innerDiv
        {
            width: 320px;
            height: 450px;
            overflow: auto; 
        }  
    
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="parentDiv"/>
        <div class="innerDiv"/>
            <ul>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>f</li>
                <li>g</li>
                <li>h</li>
                <li>i</li>
                <li>j</li>
                <li>k</li>
                <li>l</li>
                <li>m</li>
                <li>n</li>
                <li>o</li>
                <li>p</li>
                <li>q</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>s</li>
                <li>t</li>
                <li>u</li>
                <li>v</li>
                <li>w</li>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>y</li>
                <li>z</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would rather not use js if possible.

Comment: I don't mind using calc as I am targeting modern browsers and using it in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Set overflow: hidden; on the #scroll but only if you don't want any scrolling in it

```css
#scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden; /*this is the part of the code which make the scroll bar visable*/
  background-color: aqua;
  /*padding-right: 32px; /* uncomment to remove scrollbar by pushing 32 px right*/
}
```

I don't know if there was a way to do it without JS but here is my thought so far
use JS

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    
       $("#scroll").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    
          this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
          event.preventDefault();
    
       });
    
    });
</script>
```

note that you need JQuery and a plugin for JQuery called (jquery-mousewheel) https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel
or you can try this one out, it's another JS but this one is pure JS https://github.com/kamlekar/slim-scroll